# Git merge branches that are merged in remote

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch

History:

- Remote had 8 branches and I forked to create my origin.
- I created my branch and started working on it.
- I switched to origin master branch and pulled the remote master branch.

Situation:

- Remote has 1 new branch while all old(8) branches are merged to master.
- My local has 8(mainline)+1(mainline master)+1(origin master)+1(origin my new branch)+1(mainline new branch) =12 branches.

Question : how do I sync local and remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the original remote named `remote` and your remote named `origin`, try:

```
git remote update
git remote prune origin
git remote prune remote
```

You could then find your local branches which are merged in

```
git branch --merged remote/master
```

and delete them:

```
git branch -d <branch>
```

You could delete all branches merged into the current HEAD with one command:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '\\*' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Now you should have everything cleared up and you should have a lot less branches.

The actual synchronisation you could achieve with:

```
git checkout master && git pull --rebase remote master
```

(If your local branch you want updated is named `master`).

You could omit the `--rebase` flag if there are a lot of conflicts with the updated remote branch.

Comment: I have remotes named `mainline` and `origin` where `mainline` is base project and `origin` is my fork on github. `git remote prune mainline` removed most of the branches. I deleted the rest with `git branch -d <branch>`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having conflict issues? To have your master-local / master-remote "sync" up, you must manually handle all conflicts.

This is discussed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request)